# nodejs hashing multiple times

Tags: node.js, hash

I'm doing this exercise and I'm not obtaining the correct answer. I have to hash a word 3 times in a row (sha256, sha384, sha512) using nodeJS.

This is what I've tried:

```
function findHash(password) {
  const hash_256 = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(password, "utf-8").digest("hex");
  const hash_384 = crypto.createHash("sha384").update(hash_256, "hex").digest("hex");
  return crypto.createHash("sha512").update(hash_384, "hex").digest("hex")
}
```

Is it correct ? Or am I missing something?

Comment: What is the answer you're expecting? What are you getting?

Comment: I do not have the answer. I can only throw it in and I'm given back if it is correct or not.

Comment: Why do you need multiple hashes? You don't gain something extra by applying multi-hashing.

Comment: I know. It's just a programming excercise I was given